# "OK Google" too sensitive, reacts on "OK" only

Tags: google-voice-actions, ok-google

When I want to start an "OK Google" query, I just have to say "OK" and Google Search starts listening.

Unfortunately that makes the features unusable because when on a charger my phone is always active and when anyone in the office says "OK", my phone starts searching away.

Same behaviour when I start the original "Google Search" app and use the hotword.

What to do?

My specs:

```
 - Device: Samsung Galaxy S4
 - ROM: SlimKat 6.8
 - Launcher: Apex (has OK Google support)
 - Additinal Info: Xprivacy installed.
```

Comment: Did you notice this issue with other ROMs? Does Apex launcher have some "OK Google" functionality of its own like Nova Launcher does? It could be the launcher at fault, the ROM, the device, the Google Search App itself... Hard to narrow down yet. I'm using a Google Edition ROM here with the Google Now launcher and it needs both words. If you can, try that launcher (it's free) and try OK Google command from there to narrow this down a little. You can also retrain the voice model in google search and see if this helps.

Comment: Added info: Same behaviour in the official "Google Search"-app.

Comment: Cool it seems to be SlimKat but the app itself has a few quirks that people are anecdotally telling me here in the office. Seems more common on AOSP and 'Vanilla' android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching around, this appears to be an issue with SlimKat ROM itself.

[Reading this review of SlimKat](http://www.droidcent.com/2014/08/slimkat-rom-444-full-review.html) or [alternative link to article as their formatting is awful](http://www.droidcent.com/2013/12/kitkat-christmas-present.html?q=christmas), the line that jumped out at me was:

> ....talk to by simply saying "Okay Google" (**sometimes even just okay**-_-)

suggests this happens on the ROM.

Also there is a [theory](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1paf7l/there_is_a_way_to_change_your_hotword_from_ok/) that the launcher listens to OK G and starts background tasks for the searching.

> Maybe it has something to do with the fact that it listens for "OK G--" and then it starts loading voice search while you're still saying "oogle", instead of it listening for "Google" and then loading up voice search, leaving you waiting for a short while?

It is worth noting that a friend with a Nexus 4 told me that sometimes it pops up on "OK" for him but it is rare. I can't find confirmation online.

Also some launchers try to incorporate the OK Google themselves, sometimes not in the correct manner and this can cause conflicts. For example the image below is from Nova Launcher (which I use myself very often) to show you its OK Google screen which is a separate function to the Google Search app's one:

[image]

Finally some OEMs have their own "Hi Galaxy" ala Samsung and this can further muddy the water with this functionality.

[image]
<sub>(source: [futurecdn.net](http://cdn3.mos.techradar.futurecdn.net//art/your_mobile_life/SVoice/Svoice4-580-90.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I thought I can set a custom word but no I can not.

Comment: @MANI I didn't think so to be honest, thought it might be like "Hi Galaxy" above! Apparently "OK Google" is a good expression for voice recognition software to find, and easier than other attempts at it... Who knows. It works for me about 70% of the time, the other 30% I'm left shouting at the phone like a weirdo!!

Comment: Yes I am using Apex with hotword integration and even Slimkat but the thing is: I could rule these out due to the fact that the same behavour is in the **Google Search** app, don't you think? Well I might try CM as a test. About "OK G.." I don't use the word "Google" at all and it still works.

Comment: It could be the app, that's why I mentioned that people are telling me it sometimes happens on Stock ROM devices, as well as the theory from Reddit. I'm trying to cover a few of the potential issues. I'd guess it happens anyway, but SlimKat certainly seems to exacerbate the issue.

Comment: @RossC Your link to the review seems to be wrong. It links to another review of Slimkat without the quote. Here is the correct link: http://www.droidcent.com/2013/12/kitkat-christmas-present.html?q=christmas and it is for Android 4.4.2.

Comment: @sir_brickalot (awesome name btw) I copied the text out of the link I provided, it is there but the AWFUL formatting of that site is obscuring it. I'll post both links to make it easier. It definitely is there, I've just copied it into notepad. But the key line is there anyway.

Comment: Accepted your ( @RossC )  answer, because it is well written. not really convinced though that slimkat has anything to do with it... doesn't tamper with the google service I would presume. ;)

Comment: @sir_brickalot  thanks, once I'm at a pc I'll edit the wording to mention the slimkat article but move the 'blame' more towards the Google search functionality itself. I can trigger it here by saying ok g- and even Oh god at times!!